# When do we need custom directive in angular?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

directives are used to add or remove dom objects ex:- ngFor, ngIf or ngSwitch.
Or, it can be use to change the appearance of dom objects ex:- ngClass and ngStyle.

What are the things that i can't do with the above 5 directives and will need to create custom directive?

Comment: *numberOnlyDirective* - Accept only numbers in `input`, *confirmationDirective* - Ask confirmation before performing sensitive operation, and *preventMultipleClicks* - Prevent accidentally clicking multiple times for `save` button

Comment: There are countless reasons to use directives. Any time you need to modify the appearance **or** behavior of your app based on DOM elements.